# Contents of SSBO become invalid after C++ function call

Tags: c++, opengl, gpgpu

I have an SSBO named `sparseMatrix` and the following order of operations:

```
void callerFunc()
{
    func1();
    func2();
}

/* Clear buffer data store and fill with compute shader */
void func1()
{
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, sparseMatrix);
    GLfloat floatZero = 0.0f;
    glClearBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_R32F, **EDIT: 0**, sizeof(GLfloat)*size, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, &floatZero);

    /* use shader program, bind uniforms */
    glDispatchCompute(numWorkGroups,1,1); // fills buffer by adding a few numbers
}

/* Download data store contents and print */
void func2()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sparseMatrix);
    GLfloat* temp = new GLfloat[size];
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLfloat)*size, temp);
    /* print values to console */
}
```

There are no calls in between `func1()` and `func2()`.

The values that are printed to a console are garbage (every float is `-107374176.000000`). I tested this on two machines, one with a GeForce GTX 570 and one with a GeForce GT 750M, with the exact same result, including the alterations below. Driver version is 335.23.

I tried making all of the following alterations to the code (every alteration separately):

- If I move the contents of `func2()` to the end of `func1()`, the values turn out fine.
- If I move the contents of `func2()` directly into `callerFunc()`, the values turn out fine.
- If I add an additional `glGetBufferSubData()` call on the SSBO at the end of `func1()`, the values queries in `func2()` turn out fine.
- If I place a `glFinish()` after the `glClearBuffer` call or at the end of `func1()`, the values in `func2()` are correct. If I place the `glFinish()` at the beginning of `func2()` though, it doesn't change anything.
- Placing `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)` anywhere doesn't help either.

Does anyone have an explanation for this peculiar behavior?

**EDIT:** I replaced the calls to `glClearBufferSubData(...)` with a computer shader that fills up the data store with a constant value and now the behavior is as expected. But I still don't know what caused the problem.

**EDIT 2:** Thank you for the answer, but actually I used it correctly. When I posted the code here I forgot to put in the offset parameter, sorry about that :( I encountered the problem again during another long list of consecutive compute dispatches. I tried many things and in the end it helped to put a GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT memory barrier instead of the GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT barrier, although the compute shaders work purely on SSBOs. I have no idea why.

Comment: you were using that function in the wrong way :) look at answer and remember to accept it:) wellcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is how you are using

```
glClearBufferSubData
```

function.

Just look at specifications:

[glClearBufferSubData](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glClearBufferSubData.xml)

You basically providing no offset, I'm guessing why you didn't get any compiler error since you were missing a parameter

code sample:

```
GLfloat zeroFloat = 0.0f;

glClearBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,    //target
                     GL_R32F,                     //internal format
                     0,                    //you were missing this: offset
                     sizeof(GLfloat)*size, //size
                     GL_RED,               //format
                     GL_FLOAT,             //type
                     &zeroFloat);           //data
```

Edited answer to reflect request in comments:

GPU may use caches at different levels of the pipeline, so changes in a BufferObject are not immediatly visible from other stages of the pipeline. A memory barrier force coherency for specified targets so that every Write operation before the barrier will be visible after the barrier. If you have any Write operation *after* the barrier then you are in trouble.

```
write
Memory Barrier
read
```

You mentioned a long computation, then (assuming there are no drivers bug) is possible that the current content of the SSBO depends on a texture. So a memory barrier on the texture make sure the content of the SSBO has the texture data. Then appears that the memory barrier on SSBO is not necessary because when SSBO is accessed it already have the correct data (in that case you theorically need both Texture and SSBO bits setted: texture barrier before updating SSBO, and SSBO barrier before using it).

If you can reproduce the issue with small code, then it could be a driver bug.
Remember to test the code on multiple machines with different hardware because you still could get unexpected results due to missing memory barriers.

Comment: You are actually misreading that manpage. He uses `glClearBufferSubData` exactly the way it is meant to be uesd. It by the way would also be a totally useless function if it was the same as `glBufferSubData`.

Comment: Why do you say so? What you wrote makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: nope, he's still missing "offset". Now the answer is correct at least. It spots a possible problem.

Comment: OK, missed that. Sorry. Now I think this is a helpful answer :)

Comment: Np, next time you can edit instead of downvoting :D. you'll also not lose pooints for downvoting and get points for accepted edit (If you downvoted of course XD)

Comment: Let us <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59105/discussion-between-dariooo-and-derhass">continue this discussion in chat</a>.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but actually I used it correctly. When I posted the code here I forgot to put in the offset parameter, sorry about that :(
I encountered the problem again during another long list of consecutive compute dispatches. I tried many things and in the end it helped to put a GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT memory barrier instead of the GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT barrier, although the compute shaders work purely on SSBOs. I have no idea why.

Comment: Since I can't see your whole code I made some assumption, answer is updated now, it could still not be the definitive answer yet:).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer again! It is of course possible that I have missed a dependency. The concrete situation is: I'm using [PCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_preconditioned_conjugate_gradient_method) and have compute shaders for vector add, sparse matrix multiplication, scalar product etc. All quantities (x, A, b, r, z, ...) are stored in SSBOs and written and read exclusively as such. I added shader storage barriers between every dispatch, to no avail. Adding a single texture fetch barrier bit before the calculation of beta_k fixes the problem.